# Handlebars / Mustache with Rails url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use a named route with `{{id}}` as one of the params, allowing the rendered content to be consumed by Handlebars. `url_for` is escaping the param so the resulting url contains `%7B%7Bid%7D%7D`. I've tried adding `:escape => false` to the call, but it has no effect.

#### routes.rb

```
resources :rants, :except => [:show] do
  post '/votes/:vote', :controller => 'votes', :action => 'create', :as => 'vote'
end
```

#### index.haml

```
%script{:id => 'vote_template', :type => 'text/x-handlebars-template'}
  .votes
    = link_to 'up', rant_vote_path(:rant_id => '{{id}}', :vote => 'up')
    %span {{votes}}
    = link_to 'down', rant_vote_path(:rant_id => '{{id}}', :vote => 'down')
```

#### application.js

```
var vote_template =  Handlebars.compile($('#vote_template').html());
```

#### output

```
<script id="vote_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class='votes'>
    <a href="/rants/%7B%7Bid%7D%7D/votes/up">up</a>
    <span>{{votes}}</span>
    <a href="/rants/%7B%7Bid%7D%7D/votes/down">down</a>
  </div>
</script>
```

I've simplified the example for the sake of readability but question remains the same; is there any way to use a named route with `{{ }}` as a param? I understand I can just do `link_to 'up', '/rants/{{id}}/votes/up'` so please don't supply that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just overriding `url_for` to handle a custom param:

```
module TemplateHelper

  def url_for(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    return super unless options.present?

    handle = options.delete(:handlebars)
    url = super(*(args.push(options)))
    handle ? url.gsub(/%7B%7B(.+)%7D%7D/){|m| "{{#{$1}}}"} : url
  end

end
```

So now, calling `named_url(:id => '{{id}}', :handlebars => true)` works as you'd expect.

Comment: Preferable to use the decorated method such as to cover the url_for as above answer. You offered mokey patch.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is the mustache characters are not valid in URLs and are being escaped. I'd recommend creating a wrapper.

```
def handlebar_path(helper, arguments={})
  send("#{helper}_path", arguments).gsub(/%7B%7B(.+)%7D%7D/) do
    "{{#{$1}}}"
  end
end

handlebar_path :rant_vote, :rant_id => '{{id}}', :vote => 'up'
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid creating a separate method. For the time being I compromised by allowing `url_for()` to handle an extra special param: `:handlebars => true`; [gist](https://gist.github.com/1338476)